# Refractive index of Noble Gases at high pressure

Tags: optics, pressure, refraction, fiber-optics, non-linear-optics

How/where can I find(estimate) the refractive index of noble gases like argon and krypton? How does the refractive index of argon and krypton depend on the pressure, specifically high pressures of up to 10 bars? I am interested in the refractive index of the gases in above conditions for light of 800nm wavelength.

Comment: 10 bars is not a 'high' pressure. Your standard normal nitrogen cylinder is well over 100.

Comment: I only meant higher pressure than atmospheric pressure

Answer (score 1):

At 10 bars, just multiplying the deviation from unity with a factor of 10 may be good enough. Or one can use the fuller Lorentz-Lorenz equation.

Comment: What will be the nonlinear refractive index at that pressure?

Comment: @SagnikDas Dispersion should just follow refractive index. Or do you mean higher-harmonic generation? I do not know but I suspect it is much more sensitive to light intensity than to interatomic distance. On average, distances at 10 bar are just slightly less than half as large as at 1 bar.

Comment: I am searching for the non linear parameter of Ar at pressures around 0-10 bars. To find the nonlinear parameter I need the intensity dependent refractive index.

Comment: @SagnikDas Here are the third order non-linearities as $n_2$ at 1 bar: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00410677/document For higher pressures just multiply by your pressure. The full refractive index up to third order is given by $n = n_0 + n_2 I$. For Argon at 1 Bar $n_2 = 2 \cdot 10^{-7}$ cm$^2$/TW